# PHP & Mysql InnoDB gaps in auto incremental values between sequential inserts

Tags: php, mysqli, innodb

Currently I have a database with a id as an primary+autoincreamental value another field called refcode as a unique value

I noticed big gaps in the incremental value currently last id is 762480  while table contains only 16553 rows

Is there a way to eliminate this behavior ? I don't want the cron script that keeps inserting old values

Should I worry or no

Comment: `Don't worry. Be happy.` Same behavior appear then you modify your table. For example, you have 4 records with ids (1,2,3,4). Delete second record and you have (1,3,4). After, add new record and: (1,3,4,**5**).

Comment: There is no delete queries or update , Only select or insert are used and I still see this behavior I guess when I insert a record that match unique key or another row the auto incremental increase even though it's not inserted... is that normal too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be caused by deleting records - if database consistency is set well all is ok.

But sometimes can be this gap caused by failed database transaction. If gap is so big as in you case, i recommend to check used db transactions in code.

Comment: The failed queries are cron inserts that match current records

Comment: If you know about all of your failed queries that incrase auto increment field and it is not a problem then all is ok. Autoincrement fields work this way.

Answer (score 0):

You should not worry. `auto_increment` keys are sequential but in terms of the entire history of the table, so if you were to delete a bunch of records its not going to back-fill the old keys or reindex the entire table so that there is no gap.

Comment: There is no delete queries or update , Only select or insert are used and I still see this behavior I guess when I insert a record that match unique key  or another row the auto incremental increase even though it's not inserted... is that normal too ?

Answer (score 0):

That's how `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns are designed to work.The primary goal of `AUTO_INCREMENT` is to be always unique and not be consecutive.

If it were to be consecutive,then all transactions need to be executed serially(one after another) to avoid possible duplicates and scalability will become an issue.

So you need not worry about it.